# What are the recent real life use or applications of the Cauchy Random Variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

We have a short assignment on the described question and I already have gone through a lot of trash results from Google. I can't seem to find any.

I don't know where else to post this question. Please guide me! It will be a great help.

Comment: When I'm looking for something mathematical on google I always add "wiki" to get results from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: **`recent` >= `2015`**

Comment: [Linear sketch for streaming algorithms, to estimate $F_1$.](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/fa2014/Lectures/lecture_5.pdf)(Basically, using that the Cauchy distribution is $1$-stable.)

Comment: Since you are experienced in Mathematics, can you spot out any applications from that page? The only one I could find was the **Spectroscopy** one.

Comment: @ClementC. Algos for Big Data? It's still one year until we come across that. Still, thank you for the effort. I'll have something for backup.

Comment: Like @David C. Ullrich has already pointed out there are possibilities to tame Google. Another hint: Use Google Scholar and e.g. "application of "cauchy distribution"" as a search string. The results can be restricted to the year 2015 and later. I got e.g. an application in motion detection.

Comment: I wonder if this would get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com than here? $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com than here?

Maybe this isn't extremely "real-world", but it's a place where the Cauchy distribution appears where people were not thinking about Cauchy distributions:

A Brownian motion in the $(x,y)$-plane starts at $(0,1)$.  The $x$-coordinate of the point at which it first reaches the $x$-axis has a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll ask at the mentioned domain.